# Home/End/PgUp/PgDn keys not working properly with VS Code (with vim extension)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

This has been bugging me since a long time and even after lots of researching, I couldn't find a solution.

I am using vim extension for vs code.
So the issue is basically,

1. While in insert mode, if I press (say) Home key to go to the beginning of the line, and then press (say) Right Arrow key to move to the right, then cursor jumps back to the original position.
2. When I change tabs using Ctrl+PgUp and then press any arrow key, then the cursor jumps to the top.

Please help me with this.

Comment: You would probably be better submit a bug with the creator of the extension if possible. There appear to be nearly 1,500 open issues an 46 open pull requests though!

Comment: if you open an issue ticket, please put a link to it here.

Comment: I don't know what the problem was, but I was having this exact issue suddenly (previously it worked fine), and restarting vscode fixed it. I guess I accidentally toggled something that broke it...